# Meteor when many subscriptions are ready

Tags: meteor

I'm creating a chat app. I hope i can add a new "hello" message if i check the messages count of current chat is equal to 0 (Problem #1). Also i have a dictionary as a collection for translation. But t() returns EN variant (Problem #2)

```
t = function(text) {
  var res = Dictionary.findOne({o:text});
  return res && res.t || text;
}

Meteor.startup(function () {

Deps.autorun(function () {

  Meteor.subscribe('dictionary', Session.get('lang'), function(){
    Session.set('dictionaryReady', true);
  });

  Meteor.subscribe('chats', Session.get('domain'), function(){

    if (chatCurrent(Meteor.userId(), Session.get('domain')).count()===0 //true, even is not actually [problem_#1]
      && Session.get('dictionaryReady') //true, but next function t() doesn't work properly [problem #2]
      ) {
      var mudata = Session.get('my_manager') ? udata(Session.get('my_manager'), Session.get('domain')) : null,
        hello = mudata && mudata.hello || t('Hello! How I can help you?'),
        name = mudata && mudata.name || t('Anna');
      Meteor.call('create_message', {chat: Meteor.userId(), to: Meteor.userId(), text: hello, name: name, from: Session.get('my_manager'), domain: Session.get('domain'), last_manager: Session.get('my_manager')});
    });

  });

});
```

Problem #1 and Problem #2 everytime when page just loaded. So when i refresh the page i get another "hello message" on default EN locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can render your template only once your subscriptions are ready. This is a solution taken from [meteor kitchen](http://www.meteorkitchen.com) generated code.

- first you create a "loading" template

  `<template name="loading">
      <div class="loading">
          <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-4x fa-spin"></i>
      </div>
  </template>`
- Second, attach to your template a route controller. Here is a simplified version of it (but it should work):

  this.myTemplateController = RouteController.extend({

  ```
  template: "myTemplate",

  onBeforeAction: function() {
      this.next();
  },

  action: function() {
      if(this.isReady()) { this.render(); } else { this.render("loading"); }
  },

  isReady: function() {

      var subs = [
          Meteor.subscribe("sub1", this.params.yourParam),
          Meteor.subscribe("sub2", this.params.yourParam),
          Meteor.subscribe("sub3", this.params.yourParam)
      ];
      var ready = true;
      _.each(subs, function(sub) {
          if(!sub.ready())
              ready = false;
      });
      return ready;
  },

  data: function() {


      return {
          params: this.params || {},
          yourParamWhatever: Chat.findOne({_id:this.params.yourParam}, {})
      };
  },
  ```

  });

Now you should have all your subscriptions ready when your template is loaded.

Concerning the translation, you could have a look at [TAPi18n](https://atmospherejs.com/tap/i18n) package that I highly recommend. It is quite easy to implement.