# Meteor: getting route param on page loading

Tags: javascript, meteor

Here is my issue:
I am trying to make an API call when loading my page to load one entity, saving few of this entity attributes into the session - so I basically make one call, and use the attributes whenever I need them.

But when I try to get the id param from the Route, the `Router.current()` at the beginning of my script, it is null.

On the other hand, when I call the same `Router.current()` on a `helper`, I can get my param.

Any idea what is wrong / how can I get this param before calling my `helpers` ?

Here is my html where I will be using one of this attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="addCampaignInputName" value="{{currentCampaignName}}" placeholder="New Campaign Name">
```

And the JS:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) 
{
  $(function () {
  console.log( Router.current());   ==>> NULL
    if( Router.current() !== null) {
       Meteor.call("getApiCampaignsById", Router.current().params.id, function(error, results) {
         Session.set('currentCampaignDetailsName', results.data.name);
         Session.set('currentCampaignDetailsTrackingMethod', results.data.tracking_method_id);
         Session.set('currentCampaignDetailsCampaignTypeId', results.data.campaign_type_id);
      });
    }
  });

  Template.addCampaign.helpers({
     currentCampaignName: function() {
       console.log( Router.current());   ===>> DUMP DATA
       return Session.get('currentCampaignDetailsName');
     },
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because template helpers are always run inside reactive computation, and `Router.current()` happens to be a reactive data source, so when it's ready the helper will rerun with the correct value.

Since you're using `iron:router`, you could use an [`onBeforeAction` hook](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#using-hooks), because they can be tied to a specific route and are executed when route parameters are available (use `this.params`).

```
Router.route("/my-route", {
  name: "myRoute",
  onBeforeAction: function(){
    Meteor.call("getApiCampaignsById", this.params.id, function(error, results) {
      Session.set('currentCampaignDetailsName', results.data.name);
      Session.set('currentCampaignDetailsTrackingMethod', results.data.tracking_method_id);
      Session.set('currentCampaignDetailsCampaignTypeId', results.data.campaign_type_id);
    });
    //
    this.next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should load your template only once its subscriptions/parameters are ready. [Look at my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753892/meteor-when-many-subscriptions-are-ready/30755120#30755120), maybe it will solve your problem (especially the part where you attach your parameters to your template data object.)

Answer (score 1):

Your first function is likely running on the page before anything else has loaded, and it doesn't know what `Router` is. The best way to set these before the template helpers are loaded is to use iron-router's `onBeforeAction` hook:

```
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    //set your session variables here
    this.next();
  }
});
```

This way, the router should load the page with your session vars already set.